# American current source lines

Tags: circuitikz

How can i do this circuit?
What should i do to remove the initial line in the symbol of the current source?
It uses the current American source from circuitikz package but the line appears at the beginning of the circle. I would also like to know how to place the node label that is between the two resistors.

Best regards,
Max[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a compilable example document to your question that can be used to reproduce your current output to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I take it the ground connection is implied.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, I think this is some thermal equivalent circuit --- from where the heat flux come and go is not important ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the current generator is used as a shape and not as an element of a path, we will use the `node` form of the element, that is, `isourceAMshape`.

But the task has a few tricky details, which I solved in the following way:

1. The trick of drawing the generator at the end is needed because it is red; otherwise connecting the border anchor of a red element to the black line has a little glitch (try it).
2. Line color and fill in `circuitikz` have to be specified one in the path, and the other in the element. Sorry. At least it's in the manual.
3. Labels are normally aligned at the baseline, a bit above the element, to take into account depth. Now, your labels have a lot more depth due to the comma and the sub- and super-script, so I have raised them a bit.
4. To avoid strange things on the $T_{fl}$ pole, better using a single path.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0.5\depth}{#1}}}
\def\labelsL#1{$#1_{\mathrm{fl,sp}}^{\mathrm{tc}}$}
\def\labelsR#1{$#1_{\mathrm{sb,fl}}^{\mathrm{tc}}$}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    american]
    \draw (0,0) to [short, -o] ++(0,-1) coordinate(tfl) node[below]{$T_\mathrm{fl}$}
          (tfl) to [generic, l=\killdepth{\labelsL{R}}] ++(3,0)
          to [short, i=\labelsL{Q}] ++(0,-1)
          (tfl) to [generic, l_=\killdepth{\labelsR{R}}] ++(-3,0)
          to [short, i<=\labelsR{Q}] ++(0,-1) ;
    \draw[color=red] (0,0) node[isourceAMshape, fill=white, rotate=-90](I){};
    % west is up (given the rotation)
    \node [above, red] at (I.west) {$Q_\mathrm{fl}^\mathrm{cd}+Q_\mathrm{cv}^\mathrm{rd}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: why you define coordinate `origin` if then not use in the picture?

Comment: @Zarko ... Gotcha... I used it in the first version. Will remove, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Best regards, Max

Comment: @MaxMeneses, please consider accepting the anwer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers